# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server Login timeout expired (0)

Tags: python, sql-server, django

Getting the above mentioned error while running the migrate a django api app which requires creating a database in sql server. I am running on mac computer.

My setting.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': str(os.getenv("DB_NAME")),  # 'mytestdb',
        'HOST': str(os.getenv("DB_SERVER")), # <server name>
        'PORT': 1433,  # <port>
        'USER': str(os.getenv("DB_USER")), # <username>
        'PASSWORD': str(os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")),  # <password>
        'Trusted_Connection': 'no', 
        'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
                    'isolation_level':'READ UNCOMMITTED', #to prevent deadlocks
    
            },
    }
}
```

My Django version: 4.0.8 My Python version: 3.10.7
Please ley me know if more info is required. Very naive to coding!

I have installed the driver following [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16) Microsoft instructions. My pyodbc version: 4.0.34

To connect to MS SQL Server from python app.
Please ley me know if more info is required. Very naive to coding!

Comment: Side note, `os.getenv` returns a string.  There's no need to call `str()`.  Are you absolutely sure of your database hostname and database name?

Comment: The host and database name are sure.

Comment: Heaven forbid that Python should actually start paying attention to types, but the mssql-django documentation says that the `PORT` property should be a string, i.e.: `'1433'` instead of `1433`.

Comment: After changed to '1433', the program has not worked yet.